# How to declare a manifest on a closure

Tags: scala

Is it possible to declare a manifest on a closure

instead of

```
def extract[A](v:JValue)(implicit m: Manifest[A]) : A = v.extract[A]
```

something like ?

```
def extract[A] = (v: JValue) => v.extract[A]
```

Comment: Manifests are deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this declares the manifest on the method which returns the function returning you a function for a specific type:

```
def extract[A](implicit m: Manifest[A]) = (v: JValue) => v.extract[A]
```

other than that it is impossible for two reasons:

1. scala functions unlike methods don't support parametric polymorphism - there is nothing like

   `[A](v: JValue) => (m: Manifest[A]) => v.extract[A]`
2. scala functions unlike methods don't support implicit parameters. while this is accepted syntax:

   `{ implicit manifest: Manifest[String] => v.extract[String] }`

   the implicit here does have a different meaning: it makes the value `manifest` available for implicit resolution within the body of the function but has no effect when calling the function (you will have to provide the manifest explicitly)